# Upgrade python to 2.7 and Django to 1.4, but it tells me No module named *

Tags: python, django

I have just upgraded my python to 2.7 on my Ubuntu server, and reinstalled the Django to 1.4. I use python flup to run the Django application as fastcgi, but when I try to restart the application, it keeps telling me  No module named *

e.g.

```
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named *
```

The issue was initiated by manage.py file in the old Django (1.3) project, but according to the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

that's how I run the project using python-flup

```
exec python ./manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8083 maxchildren=40 pidfile=$PIDFILE --settings=expand.settings
```

> The old-style manage.py will continue to work as before until Django 1.6. In 1.5 it will raise DeprecationWarning

Comment: Might be helpful to see some more error output and maybe the part of the file that imports and causing the exception.

Comment: @JonasGeiregat I've just found out some of the projects can be started without any issue. The django projects which do have this issue caused by the ./manage.py file of Django on line 14.

Comment: Did you replace your old (1.3) manage.py file with the new one as stated in the 1.4 release notes ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Comment: the manage.py file was generated by Django 1.3, I am using 1.4 now. But I did the same upgrade on the difference server, everything went quite well.

Comment: So you are saying you are using the manage.py file from django 1.3 when using django 1.4 and you are supprised it's given you trouble ?

Comment: Jonas,as i know django 1.4 supports existing manage.py file from 1.3 without any changes

Comment: I tried to update the project layout to 1.4 style, but still the same issue. Error: No module named *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guesing by looking at django's source code that there's something wrong with either the layout of your project or your python path.

```
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Runs the following snippet (from django/core/management/**init**.py), which is most likely the cause of your error:

```
# Import the project module. We add the parent directory to PYTHONPATH to
# avoid some of the path errors new users can have.
sys.path.append(os.path.join(project_directory, os.pardir))
import_module(project_name)
sys.path.pop()
```

Comment: I found the issue, it turns out in the settings.py, for the INSTALLED_APPS, i cannot import apps using apps.*, i have to use apps.app1, apps.app2 etc. Still thanks a lot to @Jonas

Comment: @codingrhythm: If Jonas got you there, then accept his answer.